# Базовая аутентификация HTTP Laravel 7

Tags: mysql, laravel, php7.3

Здравствуйте уважаемые Эксперты! Начинаю  изучение Laravel 7.
Решил делать http basic auth для доступа к странице админки ( /admin).
В официальной документации приведен  пример роута в файле web.php такого плана:`

```
Route::get('/admin', ['middleware' => 'auth.basic', function()
{
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
}]);
```

`
Прописал я это в роутах, далее при переходе по адресу админки /admin открывается форма ввода логина и пароля.

Вопрос : как реализовать проверку имя пользователя и пароля? где  это прописывать все ? В документации еще написано что проверка идет по email вроде как.
1. Как сделать проверку имени пользователя и пароля из БД ( есть таблица Users  в ней поля email и password - если в базе  такие  данные есть то открывается админка если  нет то сообщение  или редирект например.
2. как реализовать проверку имя пользователя и пароля не из базы данных  а прописать их в коде - если данные  верны то страница  открывается.
 Пробовал  по разному  но то  при вводе правильных данных  белая страница,  то что - то еще.

Comment: Пройдите официальные бесплатные курсы от laravel (есть даже русские субтитры) и не дурите голову.

Comment: Наверное  так и сделаю. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Реализовать проверку имя пользователя и пароля не из базы данных а прописать их в коде получилось. 
Мои действия :
1. Создаю собственный контроллер командой php artisan make:controller AuthController.
2. В контроллере пишу функцию `

```
function require_auth()
    {
        $AUTH_USER = 'admin';
        $AUTH_PASS = 'admin';
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
        $has_supplied_credentials = !(empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) && empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']));
        $is_not_authenticated = (
            !$has_supplied_credentials ||
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] != $AUTH_USER ||
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] != $AUTH_PASS
        );
        if ($is_not_authenticated) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required');
            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Access denied"');
            exit;
        }
            return view('admin');
    }
```

`.
3. Роут в web.php   Route::get('/admin/', 'AuthController@require_auth')->name('admin-home-view');// роут домашней страницы админки.
И при переходе /admin  запрашивает имя пользователя и пароль  и при правильном вводе получаем открытие админки.